# Light box 5 is not working in ajax page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, lightbox

I am doing scroll page load using ajax for a project, but I am unable to show an image in light box while I am scrolling and images are loading in ajax page load.

I am using light box 5.

```html
<script src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
```

How can I do it? Am I doing anything wrong or it is not supported in ajax load?

Thank you.

Comment: I've never used Lightbox but I think you need to initialize lightbox again so it applies to new images. You probably have something like this `$('img').lightBox()` in your code, you would need to call that again after the images are appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my reinitialization code.

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
     $(function() { $('#gallery a').lightBox(); });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should reinitialize the lightbox again in your ajax response after adding the images as

```
$('img').lightBox();
```

Comment: Yes i have  missed the initialization line in ajax page .
Now its working fine .Thank you for the nice guidance  :) :) :)

Here my initialization is something like it.
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
            $('#gallery a').lightBox();
            });</script>

Answer (score 0):

I am using this in the ajax

```
$('.agileinfo-gallery-row a').simpleLightbox({
            navText: ['&lsaquo;', '&rsaquo;']
        });
```

but image is jerking and sometimes not working smoothly. showing half images.